# Spark 1.4.0 Hangs running RandomForest

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, random-forest, apache-spark-mllib

I am running Spark 1.4.0 on AWS EC2 with a test run of random forest with my data using MLLIB. It keeps hanging after a few stages. I've tried switching between netty and nio, which has not helped.

Looking at the tasks, I see the following jobs completed

```
collect at DecisionTree.scala:977   
count at DecisionTreeMetadata.scala:111 
take at DecisionTreeMetadata.scala:110  
take at DecisionTreeMetadata.scala:110  
runJob at PythonRDD.scala:366   
runJob at PythonRDD.scala:366
```

Looking at Storage, I see two RDD's: PythonRDD and MapPartitionsRDD at 27MB and 47.5MB respectively.

I have 1 Master and 10 workers totaling 550GB of storage as reported by sparkUI, and my data is far smaller. When I look at the job in the UI, it is listed as in progress, with all tasks finished. However it doesn't go to the next step.

My code for running random forest is really straight forward:

```
(trainingData, testData) = data.randomSplit([0.7, 0.3])
    model = RandomForest.trainClassifier(trainingData, numClasses=2, categoricalFeaturesInfo={},
                                     numTrees=3, featureSubsetStrategy="auto",
                                     impurity='gini', maxDepth=4, maxBins=32)
```

Here's were it hangs:

```
15/09/17 01:16:47 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 121.0 in stage 7.0 (TID 346) in 279 ms on 10.0.29.252 (158/160)
15/09/17 01:16:47 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 45.0 in stage 7.0 (TID 254) in 319 ms on 10.0.28.53 (159/160)
15/09/17 01:16:47 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 91.0 in stage 7.0 (TID 316) in 302 ms on 10.0.29.252 (160/160)
15/09/17 01:16:47 INFO scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 7.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
15/09/17 01:16:47 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: ResultStage 7 (collect at DecisionTree.scala:977) finished in 0.339 s
15/09/17 01:16:47 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Job 7 finished: collect at DecisionTree.scala:977, took 0.370436 s
15/09/17 01:17:03 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_7_piece0 on 10.0.28.139:47025 in memory (size: 4.7 KB, free: 45.5 GB)
15/09/17 01:17:03 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_7_piece0 on 10.0.29.154:38339 in memory (size: 4.7 KB, free: 50.5 GB)
...
...
15/09/17 01:17:03 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_1_piece0 on 10.0.28.139:47025 in memory (size: 4.2 KB, free: 45.5 GB)
15/09/17 01:17:03 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_1_piece0 on 10.0.28.111:47295 in memory (size: 4.2 KB, free: 50.5 GB)
15/09/17 01:17:03 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_1_piece0 on 10.0.28.211:35071 in memory (size: 4.2 KB, free: 50.5 GB)
15/09/17 01:17:03 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_1_piece0 on 10.0.29.155:53837 in memory (size: 4.2 KB, free: 50.5 GB)
15/09/17 01:17:03 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_1_piece0 on 10.0.29.158:45929 in memory (size: 4.2 KB, free: 50.5 GB)
```

**Edit:** 
Additional information on how my data is created:
My data is an RDD of type LabeledPoint from MLLIB. Each labeled point object contains the label and feature of type SparseVector

```
>>> type(data.first())
<class 'pyspark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint'>
>>> type(data.first().features)
<class 'pyspark.mllib.linalg.SparseVector'>
```

Each labeled point has the form:

```
LabeledPoint(0.0, (1080963,[44673,64508,65588,122081,306819,306820,382530 ...], [1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0 ...]))

>>> d = data.first()
>>> d.label
0.0
>>> d.features.size
1080963
>>> len(d.features.values)
2286
```

Edit2:
I let it sit for over an hour and it finally broke. Here's the error output at the breaking point.

```
15/09/17 19:36:13 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_4_piece0 on 10.0.28.233:38432 in memory (size: 4.4 KB, free: 45.5 GB)
15/09/17 19:36:13 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_4_piece0 on 10.0.28.28:58416 in memory (size: 4.4 KB, free: 50.5 GB)
15/09/17 19:36:13 INFO storage.BlockManager: Removing RDD 10
15/09/17 19:36:13 INFO spark.ContextCleaner: Cleaned RDD 10
15/09/17 19:36:13 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_3_piece0 on 10.0.28.233:38432 in memory (size: 4.2 KB, free: 45.5 GB)
15/09/17 19:36:13 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_3_piece0 on 10.0.28.28:58416 in memory (size: 4.2 KB, free: 50.5 GB)
15/09/17 19:36:13 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_2_piece0 on 10.0.28.233:38432 in memory (size: 3.7 KB, free: 45.5 GB)
15/09/17 19:36:13 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_2_piece0 on 10.0.28.28:58416 in memory (size: 3.7 KB, free: 50.5 GB)
15/09/17 19:36:13 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_2_piece0 on 10.0.28.31:56554 in memory (size: 3.7 KB, free: 50.5 GB)
15/09/17 20:33:43 INFO rdd.MapPartitionsRDD: Removing RDD 28 from persistence list
15/09/17 20:33:43 INFO storage.BlockManager: Removing RDD 28
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "random_forest_spark.py", line 144, in trainModel
    impurity='gini', maxDepth=4, maxBins=32)
  File "/root/spark/python/pyspark/mllib/tree.py", line 352, in trainClassifier
    maxDepth, maxBins, seed)
  File "/root/spark/python/pyspark/mllib/tree.py", line 270, in _train
    maxDepth, maxBins, seed)
  File "/root/spark/python/pyspark/mllib/common.py", line 128, in callMLlibFunc
    return callJavaFunc(sc, api, *args)
  File "/root/spark/python/pyspark/mllib/common.py", line 121, in callJavaFunc
    return _java2py(sc, func(*args))
  File "/root/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 538, in __call__
  File "/root/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 300, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o104.trainRandomForestModel.
: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
        at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.hugeCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:123)
        at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:117)
        at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
        at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:153)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(ObjectOutputStream.java:1876)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.setBlockDataMode(ObjectOutputStream.java:1785)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1188)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:44)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:81)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:312)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:305)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:132)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:1891)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:294)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:293)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:148)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:286)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.map(RDD.scala:293)
        at org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.impl.TreePoint$.convertToTreeRDD(TreePoint.scala:65)
        at org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.RandomForest.run(RandomForest.scala:160)
        at org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.RandomForest$.trainClassifier(RandomForest.scala:289)
        at org.apache.spark.mllib.api.python.PythonMLLibAPI.trainRandomForestModel(PythonMLLibAPI.scala:666)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:379)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: can you show more of how you created "data" I see something weird with your randomSplit

Comment: @DrVComas please see edit

Comment: This is a common bug in MLlib, especially when the problem is far complex. I've got the same problem (not Out-of-Memory, but a high memory pressure problem during the Removing RDD phase) running K-means where K>3000